# A closed ball in $l^{\infty}$ is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Definition of compact in Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed said that:
[image]

In Example 8.1 (c), he claimed that closed ball $\{x: \|x\| \leq 1\}$ in $l^{\infty}$ is not compact. Why?

Comment: For one thing, there are sequences without convergent subsequences in the unit ball: consider the sequence $e_i$ with $1$ in the $i-th$ spot, and $0$ everywhere else. What is $||e_i-e_j||_2$ , i.e., in the $l^2$ -norm? Does this sequence have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: @user99680: I think the question is about $l^\infty$, so that's the norm you'd need (as opposed to $l^2$). Although, of course, the unit ball in $l^2$ is also non-compact.

Comment: In addition to what the others have said, the unit ball of a normed linear space is compact if and only if the space is finite dimensional.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Wait, partly correct. Besides each component in vector x should belong to Real!

Comment: @Feanor: You're right, of course; I filled-in data from my own imagination into the problem; too-late to edit now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

compact implies limit point compact.

Hint : consider $\{(1, 0 , 0 , 0, \cdots) , \hspace{2mm} (0,1,0,0,0 \cdots), \hspace{2mm} (0,0,1,0,0,0, \cdots),  \cdots \}$. prove that it has no limit point. Actually you can prove stronger result that, they are discrete. But the only discrete subsets of a compact sets are finite.

Comment: {en} is not Cauchy sequence in $l^∞$, is that right?

Comment: ya. but that is not exactly we are at. what is the distance between $e_i$ and $e_j$ where $e_i$ and $e_j$ are distinct points in this sequence.

Comment: Closed ball {x: ||x|| <=1} is still complete in $l^∞$. It is not compact due to his set {en, n>=1} which is not totally bounded, is that right?

Comment: it is correct. it is a different argument. my argument is not this one. My point is, in a compact set, every infinite set has a limit point (safely assume we are in metric space). but the sequence we are having in our hand has no limit points.

Comment: So a metric space (M,d), if every infinite set in it has a limit point, then (M,d) is compact?

Comment: yes. In metric space limit point compact and compact are equivalent which is not so in an arbitrary topological spaces.

Comment: u mean elements of the set are infinite?

Comment: refer the definition of limit point compact.

Comment: Limit point compact is a new definition that different from compact?

Comment: yes. but in metric spaces both the definitions are equivalent

Comment: "Actually you can prove stronger result that, they are discrete. But the only discrete subsets of a compact sets are finite." Isn't this false? Consider the compact space $[0,1]$ and the infinite set $S = \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \Bbb{N} \}$. If I'm not mistaken, $S$ is a discrete subspace of $[0,1]$.

Comment: S is not a discrete set in [0,1]. It has 0 as a limit point.

Answer (score 3):

If the ball was compact, so would its closed subset $\{e_n \ : \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. It is a general fact in topology (and not too difficult to prove) that a closed subset of a compact Hausdorff space is compact (the metric spaces automatically Hausdorff). Since the latter is not compact, the former is also not compact.

The reason why $\{e_n \ : \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not compact is that it is discrete (open unit balls at $e_n$ with radii $1/2$ are mutually disjoint), and countable, and hence has sequences without accumulation points. In fact, $e_1,e_2,\dots$ is one such sequence. You may also just start by pointing out that this series lies in the ball, and has no convergent subsequence, therefore the ball is not compact.

In general, you might be interested to learn that a ball in a Banach space (think: a vector space with well-behaved notion of distance) of infinite dimension always is non-compact.

Comment: one small correction. only in Hausdorff topological space, compact sets are closed.

Comment: @GA316 Yes, of course. I was thinking too much of metrizable spaces. Corrected

Comment: @GA316: what is Hausdorff topological space? Im sorry that i haven't learned Topology. Could you tell me a little about it?

Comment: @Frank_W Given any two distinct points $a,b$ there exist two disjoint open sets $U_a, U_b$ such that $ a \in U_a$ and $b \in U_b$

Comment: @GA316: What is the metric involved in Hausdorff topological space?

Comment: @Frank_W there is no metric involved in the definition no? It is a property of general topological space. every metric space is Hausdorff.

Comment: @GA316: make sense. BTW, Can you introduce a textbook for Topology? And it ll be preferred if there is some solutions to the questions following each chapter in the book^_^

Comment: Topology : A first course by James R.Munkres (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=LtEPAQAAMAAJ&q=topology+munkres&dq=topology+munkres&hl=ta&sa=X&ei=eX2RUqUuzsqsB5uMgdAJ&redir_esc=y) is my favourite. It has good problems with hint to solve them

Comment: @Feanor All real vector spaces of dimension greater than zero are non-compact. Perhaps you mean locally non-compact?

Comment: @Neal: Corrected. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence:

$$(1, 0 , 0 , 0, \cdots) , \hspace{2mm} (0,1,0,0,0 \cdots), \hspace{2mm} (0,0,1,0,0,0, \cdots),  \cdots$$